# Powershell regex trouble with all matches and find-all between strings

Tags: regex, powershell

Trying to use Powershell to strip out certain, but not all, HTML tags or other codes. The codes repeat in the file so I need to operate on ALL, not just the first. In Powershell I create an array of all items I need to remove (replace with '') and a FOR loop to process each one on the file. This is my code (shortened to save space; the full list is about 20 items) and one example of the code I need to remove (occurs on multiple lines).

```
$THEREGEX = @(
 '<script (.*?)</script>',
 '<script>(.*?)</script>',
 '<style (.*?)</style>',
 '<style>(.*?)</style>'
)
for ($XX=0; $XX -lt $THEREGEX.count; $XX++)
{
 (Get-Content -path 2020allnav.html) -replace $THEREGEX[$XX],'' |
  Set-Content -path 2020allnav.html
}
```

EXAMPLE OF ONE TO REMOVE, pls remember this repeats through the file.

```html
<script>
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
document.createElement( "picture" );
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

The script runs without error but nevertheless fails to work. Problems I think I have might include: not operating on all matches, incorrect rexeg syntax, not telling the script I'm this is regex and not a string, and probably other things I'm not aware of.   Sorry this is a long, complicated question.

I *did* try to find answers to all the parts of this in Stackoverflow but I just cannot piece it together. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you want to replace all your patterns by "" so,
you could use directly the regex dotnet with the option singleline:
( you dont need to create group patern if you want to replace all by "").

```
# form an array create an OR regex  a|b|c|d...
$THEREGEX = @(
 '<script (.*?)</script>', '<script>(.*?)</script>'
 '<style (.*?)</style>', '<style>(.*?)</style>'
) -join "|"

# load file
$html = Get-Content -Path 2020allnav.html -Encoding UTF8 -Raw

#replace all occurences, considering $text is not multiline but singleline
$option = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline
$re = [regex]::new($THEREGEX, $option)
$newhtml = $re.Replace($html, "")
```

if you want to save the string:

```
$newhtml |  Out-File x:\path\newfile.html -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU! Your script above works perfectly for exactly what I need it to do. I can hardly believe it - I've been looking and looking how to piece all this together.
Thank you so much for your response.